# Printing the iterator that is being returned

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

I am having some difficulty trying to print out the iterator that is being returned. I am trying to create two iterators with some values and then return the iterator that encounters the value. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <typename Iterator, typename T>
Iterator find_elem(Iterator &first, Iterator &last, const T &obj){
    while(first != last && (*first) != obj){
        ++first;
    }
    return first;
}

int main() {
  vector<int>::iterator one;
  vector<int> a = {3,4,5,6,7};
  vector<int>::iterator two;
  vector<int> b = {5,6,7,8,9};
  cout << find_elem(one, two, 9); // ERROR ON THIS LINE

  return 0;
}
```

Would really appreciate it if someone could help fix this problem as this will better help me understand iterators in detail

Comment: Are you asking how to de-reference an iterator?

Comment: You should really start with something much simpler. There are so many errors in this code that we cannot really understand its exact intention. Try to write a program that finds and prints a value within *one* vector. And try to use `std::find` first.

Comment: Im trying to see which iterator it returns if it finds the element or value in this case

Comment: The problem is in `int main()`. Im trying to make iterator one point to `a` and iterator two point to `b`

Comment: An iterator does not point to a collection as a whole. It points to an individual element or is the special `end()`.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is true that the iterators have not been initialized, which is the bug, but this is not the reason for the compiler error.

The compiler error is due to a misunderstanding. You expect to be able to "print" the iterator to `std::cout` just like any other pointer.

The problem is that an iterator is not a pointer. It is a self-contained class. You cannot print an iterator any more than you can print an instance of an arbitrary class. This won't work either, for example:

```
class MyVeryFineClass {
public:
     MyVeryFineClass() {}
};

MyVeryFineClass exists;

std::cout << exists;
```

This won't work either, at least not until define my own `operator<<` that operates on a `std::ostream`, and an instance of my very fine class.

And that is why you cannot take a

```
std::vector<int>::iterator p;
```

and expect this to work:

```
std::cout << p;
```

Because the iterator is not a pointer, and a `std::ostream` does not know anything about it, certainly not any more than any other arbitrary class.

You could do this, with most iterators:

```
std::cout << &*p;
```

By dereferencing an iterator you get an lvalue to its contents, and its address can usually be "printed" to a `std::ostream`. So, in your case, it would be:

```
cout << &*find_elem(one, two, 9); // No more errors on this line.
```

Comment: Thanks! My code compiles but how do I test my code such that it prints the iterator containing the value "9"? If you can help me this then you have literally helped me understand this better

Comment: There are more bugs. Above all, the OP's attempt to feed the function iterators from two different containers.

Comment: @MoliswKikszsz - you can only search in the manner you're trying to search if both the beginning and the ending iterator are from the same container. Your revised code passes to find_elem() the begin() iterator from the first container, and the begin() iterator from the 2nd container. That doesn't make sense. find_elem() searches the sequence between the beginning and the ending iterator, therefore, you must pass it the begin() and end() from the same container. If find_elem() doesn't find what it's looking for, it returns end(), then you just repeat find_elem() with the 2nd container.

Answer (score 1):

Please see my answers in comment section inside the code.
This is the working code of your problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <typename Iterator, typename T>
Iterator find_elem(Iterator &first, Iterator &last, const T obj){
    //compare the value (after dereferencing the iterator)
    //can not comapre two iterator from two different container
    while(*first != *last && (*first) != obj){
        ++first;
    }
    return first;
}

int main() {
 //insert using push_back()
  vector<int> a;
  a.push_back(3);
  a.push_back(4);
  a.push_back(5);
  a.push_back(6);
  a.push_back(7);
  vector<int>::iterator one = a.begin();

  vector<int> b;
  b.push_back(5);
  b.push_back(6);
  b.push_back(7);
  b.push_back(8);
  b.push_back(9);
  //Initialize the iterator one and two with the first value of the containers
  vector<int>::iterator two = b.begin();
  //dereference the returned iterator 
  cout << *(find_elem(one, two, 9)); // ERROR ON THIS LINE

  return 0;
}
```